# IBM i command prompting in JTOpen not working with Java 9 and above

Tags: ibm-midrange, java-9, jtopen

Having compiled my JTOpen application with java 16, I bumped into the following error in the JTOpen command prompter:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.ibm.as400.ui.framework.java.LookAndFeelManager (in unnamed module @0x6d3c0d4) cannot access class com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows to unnamed module @0x6d3c0d4
at com.ibm.as400.ui.framework.java.LookAndFeelManager.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeelManager.java:77)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.framework.java.PanelManager.constructUI(PanelManager.java:3822)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.framework.java.PanelManager.(PanelManager.java:891)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.framework.java.PanelManager.(PanelManager.java:842)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.framework.java.PanelManager.(PanelManager.java:820)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.util.ClButtonPanel.(ClButtonPanel.java:101)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.util.ClCommandLineDialog.commonConstruct(ClCommandLineDialog.java:138)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.util.ClCommandLineDialog.(ClCommandLineDialog.java:120)
at com.ibm.as400.ui.util.CommandPrompter.showDialog(CommandPrompter.java:510)

Apparently, this is due to the CommandPrompter using an internal API com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows. The problem could probably be fixed by using UIManager.getLookAndFeel() in the prompter class code, but I'm not aware of a JTOpen version implementing this modification. Could anyone suggest a way of solving the above?

Lenny

Comment: Are you using the latest version of JT400?  (10.6, released 16 April 2021.)   If so, you should consider [reporting a bug](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/bugs.html)

Comment: I have, thank you.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can add the command line option `--add-opens java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: Yes, I can. Actually, I'm more worried about the lack of support from IBM for Jave 9-16 in their instrumental SW. Graphical Toolbox is apparently not part of JTOpen, so the only way to raise the issue is with IBM support. Which I did, of course.

Comment: It is a Java line command option. In NetBeans, for example, it is defined in the project properties, "run" category, VM options window.